# UIGestureRecognizer not being deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I have a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` which I add it to `viewController.view` and then when I call `removeGestureRecognizer` it is not being deallocated and I have no idea why.

I cannot figure out who is still retaining the instance, I don't have any instance variable or anything like that retaining it, only the view of the viewController and according to the documentation, when calling `removeGestureRecognizer` it should release the gesture but it doesn't.

Hope someone can help me figuring this out.

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(CustomGestureRecognizer(delegate: self))
    }

    func customGestureRecognizerDidDectectTouch(_ customGestureRecognizer: CustomGestureRecognizer) {
        print("customGestureRecognizerDidDectectTouch")
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(customGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

**UIGestureRecognizer subclass**

```
protocol CustomGestureRecognizerDelegate: class {
    func customGestureRecognizerDidDectectTouch(_ customGestureRecognizer: CustomGestureRecognizer)
}

class CustomGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    deinit {
        print("deinit CustomGestureRecognizer")
    }

    private weak var customDelegate: CustomGestureRecognizerDelegate?

    init(delegate: CustomGestureRecognizerDelegate) {
        self.customDelegate = delegate
        super.init(target: nil, action: nil)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        touchDetected()
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    private func touchDetected() {
        customDelegate?.customGestureRecognizerDidDectectTouch(self)
    }
}
```

This is just part of the code, probably it is totally useless on a real app but it is enough to replicate the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you go from `UIGestureRecognizer` to `UITouch`?  Or why do you need a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: I had to detect when the user tap on the screen in order to dismiss something, this implementation is incomplete though (I have updated my post). As for the first question, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: UITouch is not a child of `UIGestureRecognizer`,

Comment: I am not making use of UITouch, only when receiving it as a param, and the system will send it, not on my implementation. Sorry but I still dont know what you mean

Comment: Have you tried tapping view twice ? I guess if you tap on view second time, the customDelegate method will not be call. However, not sure why deinit would not be called in this case.

Comment: Yep, for the second tap the delegate wont be called which is fine, the thing is, why is not being deallocated :|

Comment: As has been said you aren't really using the `UIGestureRecognizer` correctly but as to why it's not cleaned up I think it's related to you trying to do it during the `touchesBegan` method.  At that point it's in the middle of processing the gesture so although it can be removed it remains retained for the rest of the gesture to complete.  You can test this be changing from `touchesBegan` to `touchesEnded` and it will work.

Comment: You are trying to remove it from the memory with the delegate callback. Since the call stack requires those variables it is not properly deallocated. Try removing the gesture in an async block.

Comment: thanks all for your comments! As @UpholderOfTruth said, on `touchesEnded` is being deallocated (and your explanation makes total sense), and also as @SachinVas mentions, removing it on an async block it gets deallocated

Comment: I lost a couple of hours to figure this out, thanks.